# Código não renomeia arquivos seguindo uma sequência numérica pré-definida em dicionário (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso copiar e salvar alguns arquivos shapefiles (.shp) e renomear estes arquivos baseados em um dicionário a partir de uma pasta na qual contém vários shapefiles. Cada shapefile é subdividido em categorias e subcategorias. Em subcategorias existe uma sequência numérica pré-definida. Porém se algum arquivo na pasta não estiver disponível, o próximo arquivo existente na pasta seguindo a numeração pré-definida assumirá a numeração do último arquivo existente no dicionário. Exemplo:

```
 subcategoria1': {
    >             'Redehidro50kana_2018_lin.shp': 1,
    >             'Hidrografiaprincipal_2021_lin.shp': 2,
    >             'Rededrenagemzas_2021_lin.shp': 3
```

Tem três arquivos shapefiles com numeração de 1 a 3. Porém se o arquivo
Hidrografiaprincipal_2021_lin.shp' de numeração 2 não existir na pasta, o 'Rededrenagemzas_2021_lin.shp' de numeração 3 será o 2.
No meu código eu não sei como coloco essa condição. O código só está funcionando com a numeração pré-definida, ou seja, se o arquivo de numeração 2 não existir o de "posição" 3 continuará com a mesma numeração. Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Outra questão importante, é que o código também não está copiando as outras extensões do mesmo arquivo, como ".prj","dbf","sbn","sbx", somente o ".shp" e não consigo abrir o arquivo.

Meu código:

```
import os
import shutil
import geopandas as gpd

# Dicionários com as sequências numéricas pré-definidas por categoria e subcategoria
sequencias_numericas = {
    'categoria1': {
        'subcategoria1': {
            'Redehidro50kana_2018_lin.shp': 1,
            'Hidrografiaprincipal_2021_lin': 2,
            'Rededrenagemzas_2021_lin': 3
        },
    },
    'categoria2': {
        'subcategoria3': {
            'uso.shp': 1,
        }
    }
}

# Função para obter a próxima sequência numérica disponível para uma subcategoria
def obter_proxima_sequencia_numerica(categoria, subcategoria):
    sequencia_numerica = sequencias_numericas[categoria][subcategoria]
    ultima_sequencia = max(sequencia_numerica.values(), default=0)
    return ultima_sequencia + 1

# Loop para percorrer as categorias e subcategorias
for categoria, subcategorias in sequencias_numericas.items():
    pasta_categoria = os.path.join(diretorio_principal, categoria)
    os.makedirs(pasta_categoria, exist_ok=True)

    for subcategoria, dicionario in subcategorias.items():
        pasta_subcategoria = os.path.join(pasta_categoria, subcategoria)
        os.makedirs(pasta_subcategoria, exist_ok=True)

        # Obter a próxima sequência numérica disponível
        proxima_sequencia = obter_proxima_sequencia_numerica(categoria, subcategoria)

        # Ordenar os arquivos da subcategoria em ordem alfabética
        arquivos_subcategoria = sorted(dicionario.keys())

        for arquivo in arquivos_subcategoria:
            caminho_arquivo_original = os.path.join(diretorio_principal, f"{arquivo}")

            # Verificar se o arquivo existe no diretório principal
            if os.path.exists(caminho_arquivo_original):
                # Renomear o arquivo com a sequência numérica
                sequencia = dicionario[arquivo]
                novo_nome = f"{sequencia:03d}_{arquivo}"
                novo_caminho = os.path.join(pasta_subcategoria, novo_nome)

                # Copiar o arquivo Shapefile e suas extensões correspondentes
                for extensao in [""]:
                    caminho_arquivo = f"{caminho_arquivo_original}{extensao}"
                    novo_caminho_arquivo = f"{novo_caminho}{extensao}"
                    shutil.copy(os.path.join(diretorio_principal+'\\'+arquivo), novo_caminho_arquivo)
            else:
                # Arquivo não existe no diretório principal, usar a próxima sequência numérica disponível
                sequencia = proxima_sequencia
                novo_nome = f"{sequencia:03d}_{arquivo}"
                novo_caminho = os.path.join(pasta_subcategoria, novo_nome)
                proxima_sequencia += 1

                # Exibir mensagem informando a próxima sequência numérica a ser usada
                print(f"Arquivo {arquivo} não encontrado. Próxima sequência numérica para {subcategoria}: {sequencia}")

            # Imprimir os caminhos dos arquivos copiados
            print(f"Copiado: {caminho_arquivo_original} -> {novo_caminho}")
```

Na linha 'for extensao in [""]:' eu já coloquei as extensões porem corrompeu os arquivos, porque renomeou os arquivos com '.shp'+ outra extensão.